# How to tell when AudioTrack object has finished playing?

Tags: java, android, audiotrack

I'm trying to play a PCM file in Android using the `AudioTrack` class. I can get the file to play just fine, but I cannot reliably tell when playback has finished. `AudioTrack.getPlayState` says playback has stopped when it hasn't finished playing. I'm having the same problem with `AudioTrack.setNotificationMarkerPosition`, and I'm pretty sure my marker is set to the end of the file (although I'm not completely sure I'm doing it right). Likewise, playback continues when `getPlaybackHeadPosition` is at the end of the file and has stopped incrementing. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 16):

I found that using audioTrack.setNotificationMarkerPosition(audioLength) and audioTrack.setPlaybackPositionUpdateListener worked for me. See the following code:

```
    // Get the length of the audio stored in the file (16 bit so 2 bytes per short)
    // and create a short array to store the recorded audio.
    int audioLength = (int) (pcmFile.length() / 2);
    short[] audioData = new short[audioLength];
    DataInputStream dis = null;

    try {
        // Create a DataInputStream to read the audio data back from the saved file.
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(pcmFile);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

        // Read the file into the music array.
        int i = 0;
        while (dis.available() > 0) {
            audioData[i] = dis.readShort();
            i++;
        }

        // Create a new AudioTrack using the same parameters as the AudioRecord.
        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, RECORDER_SAMPLE_RATE, RECORDER_CHANNEL_OUT,
                                    RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, audioLength, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
        audioTrack.setNotificationMarkerPosition(audioLength);
        audioTrack.setPlaybackPositionUpdateListener(new OnPlaybackPositionUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPeriodicNotification(AudioTrack track) {
                // nothing to do
            }
            @Override
            public void onMarkerReached(AudioTrack track) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Audio track end of file reached...");
                messageHandler.sendMessage(messageHandler.obtainMessage(PLAYBACK_END_REACHED));
            }
        });

        // Start playback
        audioTrack.play();

        // Write the music buffer to the AudioTrack object
        audioTrack.write(audioData, 0, audioLength);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error playing audio.", e);
    } finally {
        if (dis != null) {
            try {
                dis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // don't care
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show me how to caculate (it's mean how to read pcmFile):
pcmFile.length()
Here is answer? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097651/reading-pcm-file-to-double-array

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
            do{                                                     // Montior playback to find when done
                 x = audioTrack.getPlaybackHeadPosition(); 
        }while (x< pcmFile.length() / 2);
```