# How to find that audioTrack has finished/stopped playing?

Tags: android, playback, audiotrack

I need to play pcm file through AudioTrack, I want know to that it has finished playing or not?

My code:

```
scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() { public
              void run() {

              if (audioTrack.getPlayState() == AudioTrack.PLAYSTATE_STOPPED) {
              System.out.println("stop");  } // doSomethingUseful();
              }
             }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

then

```
do{
 if (audioTrack.getPlayState() == AudioTrack.PLAYSTATE_STOPPED) {

              // stop(); // myAudioRecorder.release(); // stop(); //
              myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder(); // myAudioRecorder.stop();
              System.out.println("stopped......................."); //
              myAudioRecorder.release(); r_start = false; }

              } while (r_start == true);
```

But none of above is working.

How can I know it has finished playing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to this post
[How to tell when AudioTrack object has finished playing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643338/how-to-tell-when-audiotrack-object-has-finished-playing)

This solution using "OnPlaybackPositionUpdateListener" that notifies when playback reached specific mark by marking length of audio length.

Answer (score 0):

```
audioTrack
                    .setPlaybackPositionUpdateListener(new OnPlaybackPositionUpdateListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onPeriodicNotification(AudioTrack track) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onMarkerReached(AudioTrack track) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            stop();

                            // messageHandler.sendMessage(messageHandler.obtainMessage(PLAYBACK_END_REACHED));

                        }
                    });
```